# Discrete Mathematics Uses

Tags: computer-science, mathematics-education, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to explain how and why discrete maths is used in areas such as programming, correctness, data types, state transistion and conditionals. I'm having a really hard time articulating it though! Can anyone point me in the right direction of some resources or help shed some light on it please?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [*Reasoned Programming*](http://pubs.doc.ic.ac.uk/reasoned-programming/) by Krysia Broda, Susan Eisenbach, Hessam Khoshnevisan and Steven Vickers.